# Footnote inside stacked enumerate inside mdframe, how to fix numbering and place the footnotes outside of the frame on the same page?

Tags: footnotes, mdframed, framed

I have a stacked enumerate going on inside a frame (`mdframed` package). For some reason the footnotes are marked a, b, c, etc.

```
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Plato 
    \begin{mdframed}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Text
        \begin{displayquote}
        ``Quote" \footnote{Reference}
        \end{displayquote}
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{mdframed}
\item Aristotle
\end{enumerate}



\end{document}

\end{document}
```

It looks like this:
[image: help]

Comment: Use `\footnotemark` inside the environment, `\footnotetext{Reference}` outside?

Answer (score 1):

As Bernhard already wrote, you have to use `\footnotemark` inside the environment.

Here's a working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Plato 
    \begin{mdframed}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Text
        \begin{displayquote}
        ``Quote" \footnotemark
        \end{displayquote}
        \footnotetext{Reference}
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{mdframed}
\item Aristotle
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

You should also remove the second `\end{document}`.